# Has child query with date filter in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two types in an index `my_index`. One is the parent of the other. The child is called `calendar` the parent is called `stock`. One `stock`can have many `calendar` entries, but not viceversa. I need to calculate the number of days where there was stock available in a range of dates (greater or equal to and less than or equal to). How can I do it?

`stock` entries look more or less like this:

```
{
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_type": "stock",
    "_id": "21321",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "description": "Screwdriver",
      "size": "big",
      "some_characteristic1": null,
      "some_characteristic2": "Good",
      "id": 21321,
      ...
    }
}
```

`calendar` entries look more or less like this:

```
{
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_type": "calendar",
    "_id": "21321-20161129",
    "_score": 1,
    "_routing": "21321",
    "_parent": "21321",
    "_source": {
      "available": true,
      "date": "2016-11-29",
      "prices": {
        "price": 2150
      }
    }
}, ...
```

The result of this query should look more or less like this:

```
{
      "description": "Screwdriver",
      "size": "big",
      "some_characteristic1": null,
      "some_characteristic2": "Good",
      "id": 21321,
      "available_days_in_february": {
          "count": 12,
          "total_count": 28
      }
}
```

A similar query in sql could look like this:

```
SELECT s.*, sum(c.available = true) as count, count(c.available) as total_count
FROM stock as s
LEFT JOIN calendar as c ON s.id = c._parent
WHERE c.date >= 2017-02-01 AND c.date <= 2017-02-28
```

Comment: By the way, the mappings are correct. I have already made some has_parent and has_child queries and are just fine. I just do not know how to filter out the `calendar` results by a range of dates.

Comment: Do you want the result for one specific stock entry or for all of them?

Comment: For each stock entry

Comment: If you have not found a solution yet you can use children aggregation describe in the elastic search doc by aggregating stock on some unique field or _uid, then using children aggregation to retrieve calendar entry for each stock and filter those on date. If you want to get the source of the stock entry in order to have more information you can use top_hits